# Altering Flex 4 stateGroups at runtime

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, states

I have a view where all the states are defined:

```
<s:Group xmlns="...." currentState="default">
 <s:states>
  <s:State name="default" stateGroups="state1,state2" />
  <s:State name="custom" />
 </s:states>

 <s:Label text="Custom" text.state1="Item 1" />
 <s:Label text="Custom" text.state2="Item 2" />

</s:Group>
```

When the view loads (with the currentState == 'default'), the Labels show:

```
Item 1
Item 2
```

And when it switches to 'custom':

```
Custom
Custom
```

This is expected. Now, I want to alter the 'custom' state, so that it includes the stateGroup 'state1'.

1. I have changed the 'custom' state by pushing a new value to the 'custom' stateGroups, but that does not work, so...
2. I have replaced the 'custom' state as such:

   this.states[1] = new State({name: 'custom', stateGroups:['state1']});

After introspecting the the view, I see that the 'custom' state now has a 'state1' in the stateGroup property.

Here is where the problem exists, when switching to the 'custom' state, the first label still shows 'Custom', rather than the expected 'Item 1'. If I add 'state1' to 'custom' and recompile, it works fine.

So does anyone have a tip on forcing the view to re-read the states and draw the view correctly?

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Would you mind describing the use case you're trying to implement? I bet there's an easier/cleaner solution than changing stateGroups at runtime.

Comment: I'm using it for permissions. Each view can have 10 or more different permissions, so instead of checking each view child to see if it matches the users access, I am altering the "custom" State so the view will show only the specific children that are available to the user. - Not sure why you would consider altering stateGroups as not being easy or clean. It's significantly easier than checking each child, I can determine and alter the stateGroups in a few lines of code...

Comment: I think it's messy, not because of the amount of code involved, but because it goes against the declarative nature of view states; the usage of stateGroups can sometimes be hard enough to decipher (by other developers than yourself) as it is; it's gonna become a maze if you make them dynamic. Furthermore your IDE will no longer be able to properly assist you if state(group)s aren't fixed. I'm actually surprised the compiler swallows it (but I assume you fool it by having all the state(group) names somewhere in the code, but not necessarily where they'll end up).

Comment: That said, I solve the permission issue with a custom tag I created. It goes in the declarations block and might look like this: `<rs:Permission target="{myComp}" type="include" role="{Roles.ADMIN | Roles.EDITOR}"/>`. A dedicated controller parses these Permission definitions and applies the defined changes (in case of the example: it will include 'myComp' in the view only if the user is an administrator or an editor).

Comment: RIAstar, thanks for your input. So it's not possible? I am simply trying to use the existing state concepts (displaying a view organized for a specific task) in a permission paradigm (where the task is based on what the user is allowed to do). I can do the "states" methodology, but I have to create a massive list to combine them all, which is downright ugly... A custom Permission manager would work; guess I try that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it was designed to be used that way, but I can't say for 100% sure it's impossible. And as you say: it's too limited to use for granular control like showing/hiding one particular button to specific users (and that perhaps for multiple components in one view). You might find this discussion on the Apache Flex mailing list interesting though: http://markmail.org/message/3njrld5lfzqj3kbo?q=list:org%2Eapache%2Eincubator%2Eflex-dev+multi+dimensional+state

Comment: Thanks again for the input. I have just written a class based on the idea of your Permission class. Instead of a single target, I've allowed an array of components. I have also setup whether to remove it from the view, or alter specific properties. In many cases I want components to be disabled or have alternate content based on the perms. Since Flex4 states now offer a dot syntax for most parameters, I thought I'd hack around changing stateGroups... bummer